# Is it possible to drive from Southeast Asia to Europe?

Tags: legal, europe, driving, planning, southeast-asia

My band and I are wanting to buy a vehicle in Vietnam, pack it with our music gear, and drive to Europe. 
Can anyone give me economically efficient information on 1) the safest route to take, and 2) crossing those borders?

We are all American, and would acquire our international driver's licenses.

Any tips are much appreciated, as there is very little information online about this. Most people suggest driving Europe to Southeast Asia.

Comment: I wonder if there is a route that's more economical than going by air.

Comment: The difficulties: you need an assurances, usually car assurance are limited on a region of countries. The car should also conform to traveling standards.  BTW In Almaty I saw an European Lorry. Cheap way: Ferry to South Korea and then Ferry to Russia. Otherwise, the costs of visa, delays for visa/permissions/checks it will not be economical.

Comment: I've flagged this as being off topic but I wish you well. Google maps can't plot a driving route from Ho Chi Minh to Amsterdam, but it can plot a walking route!